# How can I prove the lower bound theorem?

Tags: proof-explanation, upper-lower-bounds

The proof for the upper bound theorem, that I've seen, goes like this:

> A more elegant proof for the upper bound (the same logic can follow
> with the lower) is to notice that if the quotient $q(x)$ has only
> positive coefficients, all numbers greater than $a$ will have a positive
> output (and thus never cross the $x$-axis).
>
> $$f(x)=(x−a)q(x)+r(x)$$
>
> For some $c>a$
>
> $$f(c)=(c−a)q(c)+r(c)$$
>
> $$\text{where}$$
>
> $$c>a>0,$$
>
> $$q(c)>0,$$
>
> $$c−a>0,$$
>
> $$r(c)>0$$
>
> Hence, $f(c)=(c−a)q(c)+r(c)>0$ which implies that any value $>a$ cannot be a root and is
> thus an upper bound.

The problem is that they say that the same logic can follow for the lower bound theorem, but I can't find that anywhere. The book I'm using says the exact same thing as well but doesn't supply the proof for the lower bound version.

So my question is: What is the proof for the lower bound version?

Comment: For the lower bound, you can apply the upper bound version for $f(-x)$. If $b$ is an upper bound for the roots of $f(-x)$ , then $-b$ is a lower bound for the roots of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much.